# Table valued Functions and view

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have created the following function:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION ufn_sales_stats (
    @compid int,
    @target_date date
 )  RETURNS TABLE  
 AS  
 RETURN (  SELECT  DISTINCT
        E.COMP_ID, 
        E.STAFF_ID, 
        E.CONTRACT_ID,
        CT.JOB_TITLE AS JT, 
        CAST(SUM(E.REVENUE) AS DECIMAL (10,2)) AS SUM_SALES,
        DT.CAL_DATE AS TARGET_DATE

        FROM SALES E
        LEFT JOIN DATES_TABLE DT ON 1=1
        LEFT JOIN CONTRACT_TABLE CT ON CT.COMP_ID = E.COMP_ID and CT.STAFF_ID = E.STAFF_ID 
        AND CT.CONTRACT_ID = E.CONTRACT_ID
        LEFT JOIN J_CONDI C3 ON E.COMP_ID = C3.COMP_ID AND C3.COND_DATE = '20200101'

        WHERE 
        E.SALES_DATE = @date
        AND E.COMP_ID = @compid

        GROUP BY
            E.COMP_ID, 
            E.STAFF_ID, 
            E.CONTRACT_ID,
            CT.JOB_TITLE,   
            DT.CAL_DATE );
```

and I want to create the following view:

```
CREATE VIEW SALESSTATS AS
(
SELECT  DISTINCT
        SQ.COMP_ID,
        SQ.JT,
        CAST(MIN(SQ.SUM_SALES) OVER (PARTITION BY SQ.JT)  AS DECIMAL (10,2)) AS MINIMUM,
        CAST(PERCENTILE_CONT(0.15) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SQ.SUM_SALES) OVER (PARTITION BY SQ.JT) AS DECIMAL (10,2)) AS P15,
        CAST(PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SQ.SUM_SALES) OVER (PARTITION BY SQ.JT) AS DECIMAL (10,2)) AS P25,
        CAST(AVG(SQ.SUM_SALES) OVER (PARTITION BY SQ.JT) AS DECIMAL (10,2)) AS AVERAGE,
        CAST(PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SQ.SUM_SALES) OVER (PARTITION BY SQ.JT) AS DECIMAL (10,2)) AS MEDIAN,  
        CAST(PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SQ.SUM_SALES) OVER (PARTITION BY SQ.JT) AS DECIMAL (10,2)) AS P75,
        CAST(PERCENTILE_CONT(0.85) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SQ.SUM_SALES) OVER (PARTITION BY SQ.JT) AS DECIMAL (10,2)) AS P85,
        CAST(MAX(SQ.SUM_SALES) OVER (PARTITION BY SQ.JT) AS DECIMAL (10,2)) AS MAXIMUM,
        COUNT(SQ.SUM_SALES) OVER (PARTITION BY SQ.JT) AS AMOUNT,
        SQ.TARGET_DATE
FROM ufn_sales_stats('566165', '20201201') SQ;
)
```

I want the following to be variable:

```
FROM ufn_sales_stats(SQ.COMP_ID, SQ.TARGET_DATE);
```

because I want to set the parameter when I call the view later, like:

```
SELECT *
FROM SALESSTATS SAS
WHERE 
     SAS.COMP_ID = '561584'
AND  SAS.TARGET_DATE = '20201201'
```

is that possible?

[View not running - percentile_cont](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65421903/view-not-running-percentile-cont/65425234#65425234) is my original issue

Comment: You cannot do this as a view.  If you want to parameterize it, you need a function.  You already have an example of a table-valued function, so it should be clear how to do what you need.

Comment: Where is `SQ` coming from in your `VIEW`? There is only one object in the `FROM` of your `VIEW`,  and that's `ufn_sales_stats` and that doesn't have an alias.

Comment: it should be the alias of ufn_sales_stats

Comment: Then your question doesn't make much sense, @TheDev ; `FROM ufn_sales_stats(SQ.COMP_ID, SQ.TARGET_DATE) SQ;`. would mean you want the function `ufn_sales_stats` to use parameters from itself. That makes no sense; how can you pass parameters to a function, when that those parameters are being provided from itself?

Comment: No need to do `SELECT DISTINCT` here, the `GROUP BY` returns no duplicates.

Comment: Just stop throwing DISTINCT into every query without having any reason. You did that twice in just this post. Your view also uses aggregates without a GROUP BY clause - that is not valid syntax even if you could pass parameters to it.

Comment: @SMor, the OP has `OVER`, so it *is* valid syntax, however, it's the *wrong* way to do it. INstead of all those `OVER` clauses, they should have a single `GROUP BY` clause on their non-aggregated columns